# C++ Lazily return results while traversing a tree

Tags: c++, tree

I have the following tree structure:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Tree : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Tree<T>>
{
public:
    Tree(T data);
    Tree(T data, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Tree<T>>> children);

    void add_child(std::shared_ptr<Tree<T>>& child);
    void add_children(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Tree<T>>> children);

    void set_parent(std::shared_ptr<Tree<T>> parent)
    { this->parent = parent; }
    
    const T get_data() const
    { return this->data; }
    const std::shared_ptr<Tree<T>>& get_parent() const
    { return this->parent; }
    const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Tree<T>>>& get_children() const
    { return this->children; }

private:
    T data;
    std::shared_ptr<Tree<T>> parent=nullptr;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Tree<T>>> children;
};


template<typename T>
Tree<T>::Tree(T data): data(data)
{ }


template<typename T>
Tree<T>::Tree(T data, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Tree<T>>> children): data(data)
{ 
    this->add_children(children);
}


template<typename T>
void Tree<T>::add_child(std::shared_ptr<Tree<T>>& child)
{
    this->children.push_back(child);
    child->set_parent(this->shared_from_this());
}


template<typename T>
void Tree<T>::add_children(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Tree<T>>> children)
{
    for (auto&& child : children)
    {
        this->children.push_back(child);
        child->set_parent(this->shared_from_this());
    }
}
```

And I wand to create a function `find`:

```cpp
template<typename T>
generator<std::shared_ptr<Tree<T>>> find(const std::shared_ptr<Tree<T>>& t, T value);
```

Where you give a Tree and a value and it returns a generator that finds each subtree whose root node contains `value`. My question is, how would I create this generator in C++? I looked into coroutines, but they seemed overly complex for this(or almost anything). I also tried to think about doing the search with helper static variables, but I couldn't think about a way to code it without accidentally skipping nodes.

Here is a helper code to create a tree:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

#include "tree.hpp"

std::shared_ptr<Tree<int>> create_tree()
{
    // init tree and nodes
    std::shared_ptr<Tree<int>> tree(new Tree<int>(1));
    std::shared_ptr<Tree<int>> leaf1(new Tree<int>(5));
    std::shared_ptr<Tree<int>> leaf2(new Tree<int>(4));
    std::shared_ptr<Tree<int>> leaf11(new Tree<int>(3));

    // construct tree
    leaf1->add_child(leaf11);
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Tree<int>>> v;
    v.push_back(leaf1);
    v.push_back(leaf2);
    tree->add_children(v);

    return tree;
}


int main() 
{
    std::shared_ptr<Tree<int>> tree = create_tree();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This generator class gets created the same exact way any other instance of any class in C++ gets created: by calling the class's constructor. Your question s unclear.

Comment: I don't really understand what your saying, of course it is create by calling the constructor, this is not the question. My question is about how to lazily find all subtrees whose root node have a given value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can't use `std::shared_ptr<Tree<T>>` type for `parent` in your class. Since you are creating circular dependencies between `std::shared_ptr`'s and they will never be deleted, thus creating memory leak. You can use plain pointer or `std::weak_ptr`, later is probably better option for you, to keep unified interface. So, in this case your `get_parent()` function will look like this:

```cpp
    std::shared_ptr<Tree<T>> get_parent() const
    { return this->parent.lock(); }
```

Now about generator, it is pretty simply to create one. Yes, you need to keep some state, but in case of a tree there is no much of a state to keep. You can do something like this:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct generator {
    generator(std::shared_ptr<Tree<T>> t, T v) : value(v), tree(t) {}

    std::shared_ptr<Tree<T>> getNext() {
        std::shared_ptr<Tree<T>> next = advance();
        while (next != nullptr && next->get_data() != value) {
            next = advance();
        }
        return next;
    }
private:
     std::shared_ptr<Tree<T>> advance() {
        if (tree == nullptr) return nullptr;
        // Special case for first entry
        if (state.empty()) {
            // If we don't have children, this is last chance
            if (tree->get_children().empty()) {
                return std::exchange(tree, nullptr);
            }
            state.push(0);
            return tree;
        }
        // Going up, till next node, can be few levels
        while (state.top() >= tree->get_children().size()) {
            state.pop();
            tree = tree->get_parent();
            if (tree == nullptr) return nullptr;
        }
        std::shared_ptr<Tree<T>> child = tree->get_children()[state.top()];
        if (!child->get_children().empty()) {
            // Go deeper
            state.top()++;
            state.push(0);
            tree = child;
            return child;
        }
        state.top()++;
        return child;
    }
    T value;
    std::shared_ptr<Tree<T>> tree;
    std::stack<size_t> state;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement an iterator for a generator class.